# Silex 2 : removing the default authentication provider UserAuthenticationProvider

Tags: php, authentication, silex

Is there a way to remove the default authentication provider `UserAuthenticationProvider` from `$app['security.authentication_manager']`?

I have created my own authentication provider and I don't want to use the default one calling `DaoAuthenticationProvider` to check the user password because authentication process is not working that way.

At this time, the authentication manager call the 2 authentication providers : my custom and the default one. To permit a successfull authentication, I overwrite the DAO to skip the tests, but it is not clean.

**Custom authentication provider**

```
$app['security.authentication_listener.factory.sds'] = $app->protect(function ($name, $options) use ($app) {
    // define the authentication provider object
    $app['security.authentication_provider.'.$name.'.sds'] = function () use ($app) {
        return new CustomAuthenticationProvider($app['user.provider'], $app['security.encoder_factory']);
    };

    // define the authentication listener object
    $app['security.authentication_listener.'.$name.'.sds'] = function () use ($app) {
        return new CustomAuthenticationListener($app['security.token_storage'], $app['security.authentication_manager']);
    };

    return array(
        // the authentication provider id
        'security.authentication_provider.'.$name.'.sds',
        // the authentication listener id
        'security.authentication_listener.'.$name.'.sds',
        // the entry point id
        null,
        // the position of the listener in the stack
        'pre_auth'
    );
});
```

**Overwrite the DAO to use a custom calss and skip tests.** *I would like to avoid that point by removing the DAO call from the authentication manager.*

```
$app['security.authentication_provider.dao._proto'] = $app->protect(function ($name) use($app) {
        return new \Trilogis\Classes\CustomUserAuthenticationProvider(
            $app['security.user_provider.' . $name],
            $app['security.user_checker'],
            $name,
            $app['security.encoder_factory']
        );
    });
```

Comment: add security config for `sds` firewall

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick guess, but you could try overriding the `$app['security.authentication_providers']` array in order to only enable yours.

```
<?php
//...
// overriding available providers to only allow mine
$app['security.authentication_providers'] = [
   $app['security.authentication_listener.factory.sds']
];
```

By overriding it, you are [configuring the Authentication Manager with only one provider](https://github.com/silexphp/Silex/blob/master/src/Silex/Provider/SecurityServiceProvider.php#L107).

IMHO, this is cleaner than overriding the DaoAuthenticationProvider